# Computer does not turn on, flickering screen

Tags: laptop, display, battery, lenovo-laptop

My laptop when i turn it on (try to) it seems like have power and the lights that shows that is on, but the screen stays black and less black, flickering like that, and be like that for how much time you leave him 'on'

i tried other hd, see if its a screen problem, or see if apparently had some wire loose, but nothing happen to be3 the problem

im without ideas, i was almost throwing him at trash 6 months ago, but my friend needed a computer and i tried to turn on, and it did, but at some point it just make the screen flickering, and stop again, i thought was a screen problem, but the screen is all ok apparentely

could you guys help me?
btw, if it helps, its a lenovo ideapad 310-15isk

edit: already tried second screen

Comment: The first thing to do is to try another, external, monitor and see if that works. If no, then probably the motherboard or the GPU processor.

Comment: yeha, i forgot to mention that, but alredy tried it :T
another test? any thing i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background:**

> My laptop when i turn it on (try to) it seems like have power and the lights that shows that is on, but the screen stays black and less black, flickering like that. An external monitor has been tried.

**Solution:**

Since an external monitor does not work, then the problem is a hardware problem:  Motherboard and/or GPU Unit.

It is now likely time to replace the computer as it is not likely to be economical to repair it.